# Ubuntu 17.10 used to boot on it's own, now I'm getting a menu!

Tags: boot, grub2, 17.10

My brand new PC came with Ubuntu pre-installed on it; it's only 2 weeks old.  During these 2 weeks I upgraded from 16.04 to 17.10 (on stages).  My PC used to boot on its own by just turning it on.  Now (after some update yesterday) I found a menu as I was booting asking me to choose between different things. I remember from them: 1) Ubuntu .... 2) Restore to factory settings + 2 other options I can't remember.  I just clicked "enter" at the first choice which was "Ubuntu" and the system booted normally.  My question: Is something wrong with my PC?  Will I have this menu every time I boot, or is there a way to get rid of it?  Thanks.

Comment: Normally there is a timeout on this menu. If you don't select any entry it will continue with the first entry (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{~}:$ grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14
```

This is the version of grub I'm using ... I can edit `/etc/default/grub`

I set:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="false"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="-1"
```

and near the end of the file you may or may not see an entry

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
```

and then I run `sudo update-grub`

and when I reboot I have no menu .. it goes directly to the first entry and boots ..never showing a menu

if you want the menu back .. make note of what it is set to before you make these changes..

Mine is

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="false"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"
```

and at the end of the file there is also the prober entry which is commented out for looking for other OS's if you are doing dual boots

```
#GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false"
```

This setting gives me the menu for 3 seconds before it goes to the 0 or first menu entry ... (first menu entry is 0, second menu entry is 1 and so on)

If this is more complicated than you want ... you can also look for `Grub Customizer Ubuntu` in google and the first entry will show you how to install it

Then you can launch that and under the `General settings` tab there is a section for `visibility`... just uncheck the 3 items in there .. it will recheck the third one with a 0 in the box .. don't worry about that .. and then click the save at the top .. that should also make you boot directly into Ubuntu without a menu

Comment: Wow!  Thanks a lot I'm sure this will be very helpful.  I'll try first the "Grub Customizer" it sounds simple for a newbie like me.  I'll tell you how it goes :-))

Comment: Ok I installed the Grub Customizer but I don't know how exactly to access it or where to find it on the system? Help again pls :-))

Comment: all you have to do is go to your start menu and type in the search box grub customizer and it will show up .. it will probably show up after you type in grub in the start menu

Comment: hmm not sure if you are using unity .. I think that still has a place to type in a 'search' but .. I hate that interface and haven't used it for years so not really sure :D hehe

Comment: Thanks a lot.  No I'm not using unity any more; using gnome shell since the last update.  I typed it in the search box under application and found it :-)) Now I've tweaked it and feel very nervous about restarting.  Will tell you how it goes if I survive the boot.

Comment: ok :D I be waiting :D ... you should be ok as long as you just unchecked those 3 boxes and didn't mess with any other settings in there :D

Comment: YOU R A LIFE SAVER :)) I survived the boot and no more menus or gibberish lines as I boot ... phew!

Comment: glad to hear it :D enjoy :D